# Combining substrings of different lines into a single line in batch for loop

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file

I have a .txt file with some data in it, where "BARREL-5, BODY-3" etc are what is being measured, the decimal after the "V" is the measured value, and the date (sans the exact time) is being used to identify which sample the measurement belongs to, as such

```
4491 316 SS,BARREL-5,V,1.393,5/7/2015 7:47:05 AM,0,,,,13,...
4491 316 SS,BARREL-5,V,1.3865,2/17/2016 11:26:12 AM,0,,,,13,...
4491 316 SS,BODY-3,V,1.256,5/6/2015 6:45:42 PM,0,,,,13,...
4491 316 SS,BODY-3,V,1.2565,5/7/2015 7:46:16 AM,0,,,,13,...
4491 316 SS,BODY-3,V,1.246,2/17/2016 11:24:18 AM,0,,,,13,...
```

This data is exported from a (really obsolete) program in .txt format only every time we take sample measurements for a batch of parts.  The data needs to be viewable in excel to quickly determine if the batch of parts is in tolerance or not.  The problem with changing an extension and going with it is that a full line of data is as follows:

```
4491 316 SS,BARREL-5,V,1.393,5/7/2015 7:47:05 AM,0,,,,13,Blow Pattern=1-1-1,Die Set=FN3,Forge=Erie,Heat #=E150058,Job #=I2928,Lube Type=Hydraforge,Operator=Paul & ,Revision=C,Run Temperature=2250,Shift=2nd,Shim bottom Die=X,Shim Top Die=X,Shim Trimmer=X,C
```

This comes out really messy in excel, and the number of columns can vary +1 sometimes (it adds a column following the 0 in `0,,,,` if that 0 is instead a 1).

My desired output, in txt format, would look something like this:

```
Project Number: 4491,,,, Material: 316 SS
,5/7/2015,2/17/2016,5/6/2015
BARREL-5,1.393,1.3865,NA
BODY-3,1.256,1.2565,1.246
```

Right now I loop through all the lines, extract all the dates, remove any duplicates (down to a list of each unique date), and then turn those into a string in the csv file as such `,date1,date2,date3,etc`.

I then loop through the data file again and put the variable name down on a new line, checking first to see if it is repeated and if so, not echoing that variable name.  I am using the following for loop to do this (filePath is a file path and project number combined, with the file extension or name-addition to be added on as needed):

```
 for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a IN (%filePath%.txt) DO (
    set varname=%%a%
    find "!varname!" %filePath%Excel.csv
    if !errorlevel!==1 (echo !varname! >> %filePath%Excel.csv)
 )
```

My current output essentially looks something like this:

```
Project Number: 4491,,,, Material: 316 SS
,5/7/2015,2/17/2016,5/6/2015
BARREL-5,
BODY-3,
```

As you can see, I need to put the actual measured values in their proper locations.  Is there any easy way to do this in batch?  The code must be easily run by anyone, on any computer (Win 7 and XP).  The data files are unlikely to change anytime soon, so the program doesn't need to be very robust.  I am also limited by the fact that I tried using Powershell but discovered that I am not allowed to run any scripts on any of the computers...

The approach I hesitate to dig into would be something along the lines of creating a list of the line numbers for each line which switches to a new measurement name, then running *another* loop through the file and printing all the values on the same line, breaking them up based on the line count.  The lines of variables would then be concatenated to the proper lines in the csv file.

Thanks for any help.  I have edited this to include more relevant examples and details.

Comment: Why must it be done in `batch`?  Why not just import the original into Excel and use `Power Pivot` or `Get & Transform` to do the conversion?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to contain more real life examples (neutralized if necessary) and what the expected output should look alike. What is the scale of your data? You could store the data in pseudo array sif not to large. Is using PowerShell an option? It shines in this type of conversions.

Comment: When you say it must be done in batch, is it a foregone conclusion that you won't be able to use VBS or PowerShell?  And if it's not too much trouble to ask, why is that the case?  Because this is rough and error-prone done directly in batch.  It can be done, but it is difficult to make bullet-resistant, probably impossible to make bullet-proof, and intensely inefficient.

Comment: See the edit in my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

Your description is confusing and you did not shown what is the desired output, so there is no way to try to write a solution to your problem... However, your partial requirements can be obtained via a Batch file in a very simple way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "dates="
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (test.txt) do (

   rem Get a list of unique dates:
   set "dates=!dates:%%c,=!%%c,"

   rem Take the values of the variables
   set "var[%%a]=!var[%%a]!,%%b"

)

rem Show the results

echo Dates: %dates:~1,-1%
echo/
echo Variables:
for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set var[') do echo    %%a%%b
```

Using this data as input file:

```
varname1,valueA,date1
varname1,valueB,date2
varname1,valueC,date3
varname2,valueD,date1
varname2,valueE,date2
varname2,valueF,date3
```

... this is the output:

```
Dates: date1,date2,date3

Variables:
   varname1,valueA,valueB,valueC
   varname2,valueD,valueE,valueF
```

**EDIT**: Code modified to fulfill the *new* specifications

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "max=0"
set "dates=,"
for /F "tokens=1-4,6,7 delims=, " %%a in (test.txt) do (

   rem Get header data
   set "project=%%a" & set "material=%%b %%c"

   rem Get a list of unique dates
   if "!dates:%%f=!" equ "!dates!" set "dates=!dates!%%f,"

   rem Take the values of the variables
   set "var[%%d]=!var[%%d]!,%%e"

   rem Get data for variable equalization
   set "data=%%d"
   for /F %%D in ("!data:-=_!") do (
      set /A "len[%%D]+=1"
      if !len[%%D]! gtr !max! set "max=!len[%%D]!"
   )
)

rem Equalize variables
set /A max-=1
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%i in ('set len[') do (
   set "data=%%i"
   for /F %%D in ("!data:_=-!") do for /L %%I in (%%j,1,%max%) do (
      set "var[%%D]=!var[%%D]!,NA"
   )
)

rem Show the results

(
echo Project Number: %project%,,,, Material: %material%
echo %dates:~0,-1%
for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set var[') do echo %%a%%b
) > output.txt
```

The output generated by this program is *exactly the same* specified in the question...

Answer (score 0):

An easy way **by 2 command lines** to solve your question, see screenshot at bottom.

```
:: Extract all dates and get unqiue
msr -p your-source.txt -t "^.*?,(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+:\d+).*" -o "$1" -PAC | nin nul -uPAC | msr -S -t "(\S+)\s+" -o ",$1" -PAC >> result.csv

:: Extract column2 like "BARREL-5" -> Auto classify -> Extract values like "1.393" -> Add "NA" if lack columns
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('nin source.txt nul "^[^,]+,([^,]+)" -u -PAC') do @msr -p source.txt -t ".*?,%%a,V,(\d+\.\d+),.*" -o "$1" -PAC | msr -S -t "\s+(\S+)" -o ",$1" -PAC | msr -t "^\d+\.?\d*,\d+\.?\d*$" -o "$0,NA" -aPAC| msr -t ".+" -o "%%a,$0" -PAC >> result.csv
```

But I don't know how you first line come out: `Project Number: 4491,,,, Material: 316 SS`

The above uses 2 common single exe tool (no dependencies): `msr.exe` (**M**atch/**S**earch/**R**eplace) + `nin.exe` (**N**ot-**In**-latter: get difference/intersection) in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory.

Use `msr-Win32.exe` and `nin-Win32.exe` if you're on a 32-bit Windows.

[image: Extract -> Classify -> Check-Add-Column]

Comment: It's true that it's not easy to do by normal batch script, since you need: auto-**extract** -> **classify** by columns -> **check-add-column**, etc. , which need a map-list structure by coding/programing.